# Overwriting files when extracting from a tar archive

Tags: tar

I play OpenTTD. There are three versions available and I want to have all three; stable, testing and nightly. I downloaded and compiled the source code for all three with no problems. The issue is when I want to compile a new version. When I extract the `tar.xz` file into `/usr/lib/games/openttd-trunk/` the old files aren't overwritten. Instead, a new directory is created called `openttd-trunk-r26175`.

Is there any way to extract the files from the archive directly into `/usr/lib/games/openttd-trunk/`? That way I can just simply `make` without having to `./configure` every time.

EDIT: I don't think I made clear that the archive has the source files inside a single folder called `openttd-trunk-r26175`. What I want to do is extract all files from that folder, but not the folder itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring).

If you archive has one top level folder you can use `--strip-components 1`, to remove first folder from full files path.

Finaly, this should do what you want:

```
tar xf openttd-trunk-r26175.tar -C /usr/lib/games/openttd-trunk/ --strip-components 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--strip-components` tar argument to remove leading directory components, and use the `-C` option to specify a target location for the resulting files e.g.

```
tar xvf openttd-trunk.tar.xz --strip-components=1 -C /usr/lib/games/openttd-trunk/
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't think I made clear that the archive has the source files inside a single folder called openttd-trunk-r26175. What I want to do is extract all files from that folder, but not the folder itself*

I think you might want to try out the `dtrx` extractor.

```
sudo apt-get install dtrx
```

In that situation what you mentioned `dtrx` asks for you to decide what to do? From its manpage:

> Normally,  if  an  archive only contains one file or directory with a name that doesn't match the archive's, dtrx will ask you how to handle
>                 it.

```
          Extract the file/directory inside another directory named after the archive.  This is the default.

          Extract the file/directory in the current directory, and then rename it to match the name of the archive.

          Extract the file/directory in the current directory.
```

It also has the `-o` option to overwrite a present directory if you want that. So the command what you need is likely:

```
dtrx -o --one rename openttd-trunk.tar.xz
```

(Of course this can be achieved in other ways too, but `dtrx` is kinda handy program so you might want to try it out.)